# Can you guess my restful riddle?

Tags: riddle

**I have three faces. One of them looks down as the other two stand strong, side by side. What am I?**

Comment: Hi @andersj, welcome to Puzzling SE! (Take the [tour] if you haven't already!) This riddle as it currently stands appears to be underspecified, as any number of answers could fit the criteria. Questions that invite speculative answers are [closed as off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254/57742), so I encourage you to take another look at the riddle and add any additional clues as necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Isn't it usually closed as too broad?

Comment: @North Either one can work, but the off-topic close reason gives more detail into how it's broad. There's a recent [meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6629/57742) that explains things further.

Comment: I'm still not sure how I can elaborate on this without giving away the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say...

> ...a person's **id, ego, and superego** -- the faces of you -- where the superego "looks over" or mediates between the struggles of id and ego to find balance.

Reference:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#Translation -- I like the original German terminology.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you need to elaborate more to explain the other parts of the question

Answer (score 0):

Is it...

> A bedframe?

Because...

> A bedframe has a headboard and a footboard, which serve as two strong supports for the entirety of the bed. The downwards-facing section would be the square frame the springbox sits on. Sadly, I have no idea what the faces part is referencing. It does fit in nicely with the title though.

Comment: A bed usually shares a space with me, and you are on the right line to consider dimensions...

Comment: @andersj are you thinking of rot13(bz, gb ercerfrag gur guerr fgngrf bs pbafpvbhfarff)